# Float comparison less or less-or-equal

Tags: c

Long story short. If a float f is assigned with a value with 2 decimals, how is it different to say f <= 0.20f and f < 0.21f ?

Ok, here is the long story :

I was working on an exercice where I had to find how many coins combinations were possible to give back change to a customer with a given set of coins.

There was a rule when restriction was set to 1 then only 20 coins of each were available.

Here is my code

```
int calcul(float change, int depth, int restriction)
{   
    float m[] = {2.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01};

    int count = 0;

    float coin = m[depth];

    if (depth == 7 && (restriction == 0 || (restriction == 1 && change <= 0.20f)))
        return 1;
    else if (depth == 7)
        return 0;

    int i = 0;
    while (coin * i <= change && (restriction == 0 || (restriction == 1 && i <= 20)))
    {
        if (coin * i == change)
            count++;
        else
            count += calcul(rendu - coin * i, depth + 1, restriction);
        i++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

If depth is equal to 7 and restriction is set to 1 I can give only 20 * 0.01. So the operation is possible only if change is 0.20 or less.

```
if (depth == 7 && (restriction == 0 || (restriction == 1 && change <= 0.20f)))
```

I tried with numbers with 2 decimals of course but the result was not the good one. Then I tried this way :

```
if (depth == 7 && (restriction == 0 || (restriction == 1 && change < 0.21f)))
```

and it worked.

Comment: Why downvotes ? Is my english so bad ?

Comment: I couldn't follow your question, but I still know use of `float` is a bad idea.  When you want to deal with a number of cents, directly do so with integers counting cents, not with floats holding dollar amounts.  `.01` is not exact.  You can compensate for it being inexact.  But when counting cents, it is better to realize you are counting cents, than deal with .01 dollars being inexact.

Comment: Work in pennies (whole numbers), not float.

Comment: Go round the mountain. Work in pence.

Comment: Due to rounding errors, most floating-point numbers end up being slightly imprecise. As long as this imprecision stays small, it can usually be ignored. However, it also means that numbers expected to be equal (e.g. when calculating the same result through different correct methods) often differ slightly, and a simple equality test fails.

Comment: you are right. I already corrected my work using directly integers representing cents. But still. Is my question so stupid to get downvotes ?

Comment: Perhaps because there are a **lot** of questions already out here, about  comparing floating point values for equality, very easy to find.

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic.](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering just the initial question part of your question:

`f <= 0.20f` and `f < 0.21f` are different from each other and **both are wrong**.

If I understand the question, the implication is that `f` was computed in a way, that would have produced an exact multiple of .01 if the data type used supported exact multiples of .01

So f might be a bad approximation of .20 on the high side so `f <= 0.20f` gives you the "wrong" answer and `f < 0.21f` is right.  But another time through, f might be a bad approximation of .21 on the low side, so `f <= 0.20f` gives you the right answer but `f < 0.21f` gives you true when you wanted false.

If you must work with moderately bad approximations of multiples of .01 compare to constants that split the difference:  `f <= .205`  But then are you sure your approximations are only moderately bad?  Maybe they are so bad that splitting the difference fails.

Bottom line remains that cents should be represented as integer number of cents not .01 * float number of dollars.

Comment: Using integer math is fine when money operations consists solely of `+,-,*`, `0.01` represents the smallest unit and overflow is not a concern. Yet move into problems where costs are fractions of cents (or 3 for a $) or calculations of tax rates like 7% or [mortgage interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_loan#Principal_and_interest) calculations and code rapidly finds itself back into the floating point world.  Proper rounding (eschewed in "approximations of multiples of .01" paragrah) is a fact of finical computation and not something that can be avoided by using integer math.

Comment: @chux, The original question was clearly about a simple problem involving integer numbers of cents, so this is not the place for a general discussion of data types for advanced financial computations.  But long long ago, when I was employed in programming advanced financial computations, I did everything fixed point (quite a lot of values needed more than two places to the right of the fixed point, but still fixed point).  Ultimately, long computations get back to cents and need to be provably the correct number of cents.  Rounding must occur.  Rounding "errors" must not.

Answer (score 1):

When using floating point for exact math, like with money, take into account the inexactness of FP math.

Consider every money value will at best be *near* a multiple of the lowest unit (0.01).

Alter code accordingly

```
 #define MIN_DENOMINATION 0.01f

 float roundm(float x) {
   return roundf(x/MIN_DENOMINATION) * MIN_DENOMINATION;
 }

 // change <= 0.20f
 change <= (0.20f + MIN_DENOMINATION/2)

  // coin * i <= change
  coin * i <= (change + MIN_DENOMINATION/2)

  // coin * i == change
  roundm(coin * i) == roundm(change) // or
  roundm(coin * i - change) == 0.0f

  // rendu - coin * i
  roundm(rendu - coin * i)
```

---

Other choices include

1. Use a decimal floating point, if available.
2. Scale values in the smallest monetary unit.  (e.g * 100)
3. Using `double` works better than `float`, but has similar ligations, just further out.
4. Use scaled integer math.  Be careful about rounding as integer math truncates toward 0 rather than round to nearest.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point will never be 100% accurate for these sort of things - even reading in `0.10` will result in a value something like `0.0999996`, so it's not EXACTLY 0.1 any longer. Never mind after you have done some math on it. If you still MUST compare values that are inprecise, the method is to do `if ( abs(a - b) < epsilon ) ...` where `epsilon` is your margin for values that are no longer equal - for money, you could use `0.0001` or `0.001` for example, as if it's within a hundreth or a tenth of a cent, it's probably the right value.

Whenever I have to deal with money in programs [where the value actually matters, not a "if the mortgage interest rate is 3%, how much money can I borrow with a salary of $20000" type math problems, where a few cent here or there doesn't matter anyway], I prefer use integer values.

One can use a struct of two int's to represent it as "dollars" and "cent" (or "euro" and "cents", "pounds" and "pence", old "pounds", "shillings" and "pence", "kronor" and "öre", or whatever currency you use).

I prefer to use an integer to count the smallest fraction as a large number ("cents", "pence", "öre", etc) as one integer value, so 1 dollar [etc] is the value 100. [Obviously, old style "Pounds, shilling and pence" would make for a more interesting splitting back to "human readable" form, but otherwise it's the same principle]. This is also how most people deal with other "tricky" units, such as using seconds to represent time, rather than seconds, hours, minutes, days, etc. And dates are counted as "seconds from a certain time", so instead of a load of different numbers (1843, 6, 7 for 7th of June 1843, you'd get a large number of some sort).

Especially in modern computers with 64-bit integer, these things are pretty unrestricted, unless you are counting the national debt of all countries in turkish lira, or some such.

Answer (score -1):

Floats and doubles are stored in the machine as binary. Therefore, while 0.20 looks like a nice clean number to you, it's actually a repeating decimal in binary. Thus, the number isn't EXACTLY 0.20 in the machine. It's really either very, very slightly more or less than 0.20, so the comparison fails to behave as you expect.

Specifically, 0.20 in decimal is 0.0011001100110011... in binary.

To correct for this, NEVER expect a float or double to be EXACT, just approximate, and you'll be fine.

So, change this

```
change <= 0.20
```

to this

```
change < 0.2001f
```

and you'll be well within the range of accuracy of a float.

The code in the original question will have the exact same problem when using

```
change < 0.21
```

because a value of 0.21 MIGHT fall on the lower end of 0.21, and this will evaluate to true. This is because you're using an accuracy range of 0.01, which is not good enough for the data you'll encounter.

Comment: 0.21 is less than 800. Once you do the math, the exponent will be shifted accordingly, and you'll have the precision for this calculation. If the numbers are so large this becomes a problem, it's because floats don't have the precision to do the original calculation effectively, not because of this check.

Comment: Also, this appears to be an exercise, and the person needs to learn how to properly handle floating point calculations. Additionally, the calculation involves giving coins to a customer, so $800 change in coins seems a bit extreme for this exercise. If this were production code, then yes, DO NOT use floats to store bank accounts.

Comment: I don't believe that's correct.  The check you're proposing is two (decimal) orders of magnitude below the precision required to hold the values themselves.  That artificially reduces the dynamic range of the program by two orders of magnitude.

Comment: I agree with your concern, that this starts to get flaky with larger values. However, the real problem is trying find a relatively small difference between two large numbers, which floats are unable to do. So, you're technically correct that it will have a somewhat smaller (1-2 orders of magnitude) range with my 0.2001f value. However, the problem itself is caused by the original calculation of the difference. At any rate, the real question is why the code wasn't working, not the best way to implement a digital bank teller. Also, applying this sort of range to floats is fairly common practice.